# L'ordre du corps

Tags: sens, expressions

Que signifie « l’ordre du corps » dans ce passage :

> Essoufflé, une fois à la terrasse je ne savais l’ordre du corps. Elle, elle en profitait pour me raconter des histoires.

Comment: D'où cela est-il extrait ? Sans plus de contexte j'avoue ne pas y voir autre chose qu'une formule poétique pour signifier que le locuteur est chamboulé, n'a plus les idées claires. Peut-être à cause de ce qui l'a essoufflé...

Comment: le source du passage n'est pas un document publié. Mais vu le contexte je pense que vous êtes raison, on veut dire «chamboulé », et j'ai posé la question pour m'assurer. Mille merci

Comment: On a _ne pas savoir_ qui précède. Si on avait _savoir distinguer_, on pourrait imaginer davantage que ce serait l'un de l'autre. Dans Furetière on trouve _l'ordre du corps est interrompu_, métaphysique. Sartre dit : « Il y a (...) un ordre du corps. Mais il est manifeste que cet ordre n'est pas purement biologique. Il s'est fait sans les mots, contre les mots; pourtant il ne peut être aveugle ». D'accord ? Autrement ce pourrait être l'_ordre du jour_ d'une assemblée législative, voir littéralement un ordre d'un corps quelconque (militaire etc.). Il faut présenter les phrases d'avant/d'après.

Answer (score 2):

Dans [ce billet de blog](https://lesballetonautes.com/2013/07/13/lordre-des-choses-ou-tout-est-chamboule/), on peut constater l'emploi de "l'ordre des choses" avec "tout est chamboulé". Je pense que dans la littérature, cette expression est plus commune que "l'ordre du corps". Néanmoins on voit bien que l'idée est la même, celle du chamboulement lorsque que l'ordre est perturbé, comme l'a indiqué @Laurent en commentaire.

On a ici un autre emploi intéressant de "l'ordre des choses", dans la poésie :

> [image: Extrait de Per il bene di tutti]
>
> Extrait de *Pour le bien de tous*, traduction de Laura Brignon du texte original *Per il bene di tutti*, Francesco Randazzo, depuis [Google Books](https://books.google.fr/books?id=SlH0lTK_qJsC&pg=PA15&lpg=PA15&dq=%22l%27ordre%20des%20choses%22%20chamboul%C3%A9&source=bl&ots=bYTEZPUnwF&sig=ACfU3U0Bj8c1Wkws9h5-iYuzyF1e21Utfg&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjY-8ycqcriAhWIDWMBHdQsD84Q6AEwB3oECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22l'ordre%20des%20choses%22%20chamboul%C3%A9&f=false)